# a PDE problem involving divergence

Tags: partial-differential-equations

> Consider the PDE on a bounded smooth domain $\Omega \subset R^n$, $\triangle u(x)= 0$ on $\Omega$, $\frac{\partial u(x)}{\partial n}|_{\partial \Omega}=g(x)$. Prove that if it admits a smooth solution u, we have $\int_{\partial \Omega} g d \sigma=0$

I know that $\triangle u=div(\triangledown u)$. Can someone give me a hint to do this?

Comment: Hint: Use the divergence theorem on $\int_\Omega \Delta u =0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have

$\nabla \cdot \nabla u = \triangle u = 0 \tag 1$

on $\Omega$.  Thus the divergence theorem yields

$\displaystyle \int_{\partial \Omega} \nabla u \cdot \mathbf n \; dS = \int_\Omega \nabla \cdot \nabla u; dV = \int_\Omega 0 \; dV = 0, \tag 2$

where $\mathbf n$ is the outward-pointing unit normal vector field on $\partial \Omega$ and $dS$ is the volume element on $\partial \Omega$; but on $\partial \Omega$ we have

$\nabla u \cdot \mathbf n = \dfrac{\partial u}{\partial n} = g = 0, \tag 3$

whence

$\displaystyle \int_{\partial \Omega} g \; dS = 0. \tag 4$